# DAML smart contract uses JVM can we replace it to webaseembly?

Tags: daml

Since all the blockchain technologies are looking forward to webassembly, its better to write contract which is fits in webassembly environment. But DAML currently uses JVM. Can we replace it to webassembly?

And whats the reason for using JVM rather than Webassembly?

Answer (score 1):

We built a JVM based interpreter to be able to leverage the JVM ecosystem and the Java SDKs provided by many of the existing ledgers.

There is no fundamental obstacle to compiling DAML's core language [DAML-LF](https://github.com/digital-asset/daml/blob/master/daml-lf/spec/daml-lf-1.rst) to WebAssembly. As of 2019-06-20, support for this compilation has not yet been built.

Comment: Thanks for reverting. Is there any plan for webassembly??

Comment: Is DAML smart contrct compatible with any blockchain technology?